# Search for a large block of lines across directory

Tags: bash, string-matching

I have found that a large section of json I am pretty sure has been copied to about 80 files.
I have that section edited down into FILEA, it is 95 lines of text.

I want to `grep -lr -F FILEA .` EXCEPT, I wan't to list all files where ALL lines of FILEA exist, exactly the same in the other files.

I have thought of trying to use -P and a giant grep string with \n conversion, but I don't think that will work due to command line length issues.

For example, FILEA is

```
It was the best of times
It was the worst of times
Call me Ishmael
Here's looking at you kid
```

I want something like a grep command that I can feed in that file, and a source directory, and find all files that have exactly all four of those lines in that exact order.

I tried `grep -F` but that was per line.  I tried `grep -P` but that made the command line huge

Update: better example

```
{
   "lines": [
"It was the best of times",
"It was the worst of times",
"Call me Ishmael",
"Here's looking at you kid"
],
   "section": {
      "foo": "bar"
   }
}
```

Comment: *"all files that have exactly all four of those lines in that exact order"* .Please confirm that they should also be adjacent, as the lines could the in that order, but separated by other lines. Interesting problem. Will consider it while walking dog! Good luck.

Comment: This would not be too hard in a scripting language like Python or Perl.  Do you know either?

Comment: I know python and perl.  would you just read the file into a variable then read each of the the other files into memory and look for contains, and walk the directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One potential option is to use AWK, e.g.

Example data:

```
cat file_a.txt
It was the best of times
It was the worst of times
Call me Ishmael
Here's looking at you kid

cat test1.txt
sad;kbvhs;bn
It was the best of times
It was the worst of times
Call me Ishmael
Here's looking at you kid
slgfjswkdjv
dalkalskv

cat test2.txt
asfgasrgljnsfbklvm
It was the best of times
It was the worst of times
Call me Ishmael
sdvndslfjbn
s;ldknfvl;ksmnv

cat test3.txt
asfgasrgljnsfbklvm
It was the best of times
It was the worst of times
Call me Ishmael
sdvndslfjbn
Here's looking at you kid

cat test4.txt
asfgasrgljnsfbklvm
It was the best of times
It was the worst of times
Call me Ishmael

Here's looking at you kid

# test1.txt has the full file_a.txt string
# test2.txt doesn't have the full string
# test3.txt has the full string, but in the wrong order
# test4.txt has the full string, but there is a newline in the string
```

Solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=""} NR==FNR{a = $0; next} NR>FNR{if($0 ~ a) {print FILENAME}}' file_a.txt test*.txt
test1.txt

# test1.txt is the only file with the full file_a.txt string
```

Nicer formatting and comments:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    RS = ""             # change record separator from newline to blank
}

NR == FNR {             # for file_a.txt
    a = $0              # assign the paragraph to the variable a
    next
}

NR > FNR {              # for the test files
    if ($0 ~ a) {       # if the file_a.txt string is found
        print FILENAME  # print the filename
    }
}' file_a.txt test*.txt
```

### Update

Thanks for updating your example @SteveHammond, here is an updated solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=""} NR==FNR{a = $0; next} NR>FNR{if($0 == a) {print FILENAME}}' file_a.txt test*
```

Comment: I tried this but got zero output.  I don't know awk well enough to debug.  And other solution worked.

Comment: I tried this but got zero output.  
I took out the if, and it prints filename.  I changed to print a and it truly prints FILEA contents.  but the if statement seems to always be false.
Seems to be a problem with brackets.  if I do a small subset that doesnt have [ ] it works.  I will update my example

Comment: they are not in a single directory.  but I can always do `find . -name *.conf | while read file do <....> ; done`

Comment: Changing $0 ~ a to $0 == a works.  The ~ tries to expand a regex.

Comment: Oh, fantastic, so changing `$0 ~ a` to `$0 == a` solves your problem? Otherwise I was going to suggest parsing the json with `jq` first to extract the relevant section (e.g. `jq -r '.lines[]' < test.json`), but sounds like there's no need

Comment: Using `~` could be a problem, since it treats `a` as regular expression. This does not bite you with your concrete data, since they don't contain a regex character, but imagine what happens if the input data would contain a period (`.`) or an asterisk (`*`)!

Answer (score 2):

Would you please try the following:

```
grep -lrPz "$(awk -v ORS='\\n' '{gsub(/[[{(*+?|\.^$]/, "\\\\&")} 1' FILEA)" .
```

- The `awk` script concatenates all lines in `FILEA` by converting newlines to literal "\n" strings. Then escape regex metacharacters by prepending backslashes.
- `-P` option to `grep` interprets "\n" as a newline character.
- `-z` option changes the input record separator to a NUL character.

Comment: This is unhappy due to json braces and brackets I assume.  grep: range out of order in character class

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I've updated my code to escape regex metacharacters in FILEA. Could you please test it?

Comment: Yes, this solution works now also.  Hard to pick a best solution, the awk one has less symbols, so I went with that one.